# Unescape special characters correctly from the URL in Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, encoding, escaping

I'm using Rails 3.0.3 with REE ( Ruby 1.8.7 ) and gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'

There's a search feature in my project that enable people to use the GET method using URL or using forms and then generate the URL.

**Example:**

I want to search:

origin city: "**Århus, Denmark**" and destination city: "**Asunción, Paraguay**"

they both have a special character: "**Å**" and "**ó**", so the URL will be generated like this when someone click the search button.

```
?&origin=%C5rhus%2C%20Denmark&destination=Asunci%F3n%2C%20Paraguay
```

**Problem:**

When i search that city, it's not unescaped like i want ( i tried using like CGI, URI, even some gems).

When i see at the console, ActiveRecord received the query like this:

```
Parameters: {"destination"=>"Asunci�n, Paraguay", "origin"=>"�rhus, Denmark", "sort"=>"newest"}
City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE (`cities`.`name` = '�rhus') ORDER BY cities.name ASC
City Load (6.8ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE (`cities`.`name` = 'Asunci�n, Paraguay') ORDER BY cities.name ASC
```

*Conclusion: the cities can't be found* :(

But, i found an interesting thing:

- When i made an error on the file asociated with this function, the output will be like this :

  Request

  ```
  Parameters:
  {"destination"=>"Asunción,
  Paraguay",
  "origin"=>"Århus,
  Denmark",
  "sort"=>"newest"}
  ```

it's a valid one!

**Question:**

Do you guys have an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, it looks like you have an encoding problem somewhere. The 0xC5 character is "Å" in [ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1), in UTF-8 it would be `%C3%85` in the URL.

I suspect that you're using JavaScript on the client side and that your JavaScript is using the [old `escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.escape) function to build the URL, `escape` has some issues with non-ASCII characters. If this is the case, then you should upgrade your JavaScript to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead. Have a look at this little demo and you'll see what I'm talking about:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/U5A3k/

If you can't change the client-side script then you can do it the hard way in Ruby using [`force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) and [`encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-encoding):

```
>> s = CGI.unescape('%C5rhus%2C%20Denmark')
=> "\xC5rhus, Denmark"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
>> s.force_encoding('iso-8859-1')
=> "\xC5rhus, Denmark"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
>> s.encode!('utf-8')
=> "Århus, Denmark"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

You should get something like `"\xC5rhus, Denmark"` from `params` and you could unmangle that with:

```
s = params[:whatever].force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Dealing with this on the server side would be a last resort though, if your client-side code is sending back incorrectly encoded data then you'll be left with a pile of guesswork on the server to figure out what encoding was actually used to get it into the URL.

Comment: Yay! i used 'escape' function to build the URL in Javascript before, and now i'm using 'encodeURIComponent' as you told and it works :D Thank you for saving my day :)