# Strange InvalidURIError for '|' character?

Tags: ruby, uri

OK, so my situation is rather simple :

**Code :**

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=Italy|France&prop=revisions&rvprop=content";
xml = open(url).read
```

When `titles` is set to, e.g. `Italy`, it works fine, but setting it to `Italy|France` seems to be causing issues. (supposedly its problem is the `|` character?)

**Here's the error :**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=France|Italy&prop=revisions&rvprop=content (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
    from test.rb:41:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

**Refer:**[Unescape special characters correctly from the URL in Rails 3.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889220/unescape-special-characters-correctly-from-the-url-in-rails-3-0-3)

Also try:

```
CGI.escape(url);
```

Comment: Well, how is this method accessible? I'm not a Ruby guru (just trying it out actually), but this is *not* part of Rails project. It shows an error : `undefined method 'encodeURIComponent' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Hmmm... Just tried `CGI.escape` just for the `titles` param value, and I think I got it working... :-)